# VirtualBox installation problem under Debian 11

Tags: debian, virtualbox, kernel-modules

I tried installing VirtualBox 6.1 under Debian 11 Bullseye.
I followed the tutorial from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61248316/17596739) to [Sign virtual box modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) Centos 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61248315/4424636). However, I can not allow to disable secure boot and so I follow the second method.

First I create private keys and reboot after importing them with mokutil. I set my password, reboot, follow steps and do as requested. This worked OK.

Then I try signing kernels modules. This is where problems began: **modinfo -n vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp are not found**. I go and look for kernels modules using the find command, and I find them (`vboxdrv.ko`, `vboxnetflt.ko`, `vboxnetadp.ko`). So I signed them, and restarted them with `systemctl`.

Then, second problem. When I start `/sbin/vboxconfig`, it tells me to sign the `vboxdrv`, `vboxnetflt` and `vboxnetadp` modules. But I just signed them !

I go and execute `modinfo -n vboxdrv`, `vboxnetflt`, `vboxnetadp` again, and here they are found but under a different directory. I tell myself this could be a bug, so I reboot, and after rebooting I'm welcomed with an error message saying something around :

```
Failed to load options : Invalid Parameter
set_second_stage() failed : Invalid Parameter
Something has gone seriously wrong : shlm_init() failed : Invalid Parameter
```

I panicked and went into BIOS, checked my boot parameters but **did not change a parameter** and as nothing changed I reboot. And it worked fine this time. So I go and check `modinfo -n vboxdrv`, `vboxnetflt`, `vboxnetadp` again, and here they are not found.

As you guessed, this now loops. When I boot up, if I don't open BIOS, the error will be outputted again and my laptop won't start.

Also, if this can help, here is the result of `dmesg | grep VirtualBox`:

```
[    1.170571] integrity: Loaded X.509 cert 'VirtualBox: 'b9e568a3ad346<something_else>'
```

The `mokutil --list-import` command returns my created key as the second key, so I would say it is correctly loaded and imported.

Please help me as I could not find any other topics related to this error, I did not change any boot parameters but I get this nasty error on bootup now!

If required I can edit my question to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following mokutil commands, I could fix my problem.

```
(in any directory, if you deleted your .der key file)
mokutil -l (check which key you want to delete)
mokutil --export (dumps the keys in numbered files, do NOT delete the wrong key)
mokutil --delete key_name_here (password prompt, note it somewhere)
reboot
```

On reboot, you'll be granted my an error similar to the second_stage() one, but simply boot into BIOS, don't change anything and simply reboot. You will be prompted with the mokutil menu.

However VirtualBox still is not signed.